# Segmentation fault with strlen when not ever using strlen?

Tags: c, arrays, string, segmentation-fault, strlen

I have some code which takes a file, reads each line into a new string array (and adds 128 to each character), then assigns each array into an array of pointers, then prints each array. When trying to run the code I get an error stating a segmentation fault due to:

`strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
106 ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S: No such file or directory.`

But I never actually call strlen inside my code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define ROW 10
#define COL 40
#define ARGS 2
#define FLIP_VALUE 128

char** read_file (char* argv[], char **array_pointers);
char* new_array (void);
void print_strings (char** array_pointers);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char **array_pointers = NULL;
    if (argc == ARGS)
    {
        array_pointers = read_file(&argv[1], array_pointers);
        print_strings(array_pointers);
    }
return 0;
}

char** read_file (char* argv[], char **array_pointers)
{
    FILE* file_name;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    char c;
    char *temp_array;
    array_pointers = malloc(sizeof(char*) * ROW);
    file_name = fopen(argv[0], "r"); 
    assert(file_name);
    if (file_name) /* if file is not null */
    {
        while (c != EOF) /* while not equal to end of file */
        {
            for (j = 0; j < ROW; j++) /* for each row */
            {
            temp_array = new_array(); /* generate a new array for each new string (row) */
                for (i = 0; i < COL; i++) /* for each char in a row */
                {
                    c = fgetc(file_name);
                    temp_array[i] = c + FLIP_VALUE;
                }
            array_pointers[j] = temp_array; /*assign array pointers to point at each new temp_array */
            }   
        }
    }
    return array_pointers;
}

char* new_array (void)
{
    char* temp;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * COL);
    assert(temp);
    return temp;    
}           

void print_strings (char** array_pointers)
{
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < COL; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n",array_pointers[i]);
    }
}
```

The full stack trace reads as:

```
#1  0x00007ffff7a84e3c in _IO_puts (str=0x0) at ioputs.c:36
        result = -1
        len = <optimised out>
#2  0x0000000000400806 in print_strings (array_pointers=0x602010)
    at array_of_string_arrays.c:65
        i = 10
#3  0x00000000004006a1 in main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdff8)
    at array_of_string_arrays.c:19
        array_pointers = 0x602010
```

Comment: Suggest you run your program in the debugger and get at least a full stack trace.

Comment: `c` should be an `int`, otherwise `while (c != EOF)` will never be `false`. You are also creating a new array for each `char`, not for each new string.

Comment: It looks like your conditionals in the for loops need to be just `j < ROW` and `i < COL`

Comment: Your `while (c != EOF)` loop is wrong.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/why-is-while-feof-file-always-wrong

Comment: Adding `128` to each `char` in a string and then try to print it with `"%s"` will not print something readable.

Comment: @mch the chars inside the file are all negative to begin with, strangely. hence the +128 conversion

Comment: I wonder, does `fgetc` return a `NUL` char before returning `EOF`?

Comment: @mch and user2697817r i've made those changes, thanks.

Comment: `c` **must** be of type `int`!

Comment: Your code is wrong on multiple levels: `c` should be an `int` for `EOF` as already  mentioned, you should test `c` for EOF before adding it to the array or you are going to add `EOF` to your array, you should not create an array for each `char` but for each row, you should terminate your array with `\0` or `printf` will probably crash (hence your segfault) and you should loop up to `ROW` not `COL` in `print_strings`.

Comment: Are you sure that `assert` does not use `strlen`?

Comment: [Compile with all warning enabled.](http://justpaste.it/prhr)

Comment: @pmg That's really useful, thanks! :)

Comment: I suggest you write a function that, given a FILE*, returns a single line. Write `main` that calls this function and prints the result. Then do the same in a loop while you get to EOF. Then, *when you test and debug that function and get it working perfectly*, write a function that calls the first one and reads an array of lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are actually several bugs here:

1. In `read_file`, `c` is initially undefined when first compared to `EOF`.  Do you even need this outer loop?
2. You should check the result of `fgetc` as soon as it returns to see if it's `EOF`.
3. You are allocating a new `temp_array` for each character of each row, rather than once for each row.  This needs to be moved up into the containing loop.
4. In `print_strings`, you are iterating over the rows so you should compare the loop index to `ROW`, not `COL`.
5. When printing a row, you are using `%s` in a `printf`.  You can't do that, since there is no guarantee that the characters in a row are null-terminated.  You could force them to be, by allocating an additional character and storing `'\0'` in it, or you could include a length field in the format specifier to limit the length (you can use `*` to pass it as an argument).

I suspect the last bug is the one that's causing the segmentation fault.

Answer (score 5):

In `print_strings` you print the string using `printf("%s", str);`. This requires the string to be null terminated. The strings you write are not null terminated if you are reading an ordinary text file. You need to add the terminating null byte to the strings you read - or you cannot use `printf`.

The reason you get a crash is that your `printf` seems to check first how long the string is (using `strlen`) before printing it out. `strlen` increments the char pointer until it reads a null byte. Since you don't have any in the string, `strlen` reads past the buffer and finally either reads a null byte somewhere in memory or crashes if it is not allowed to read that memory.

Answer (score 3):

After

```
temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * COL);
```

you should

```
memset(temp,0,sizeof(char) * COL);
```

because `strlen` is end by reading `0`.

Comment: Alternatively use `calloc()` or set first (or last) byte allocated to 0. Setting entire array to zero is generally a good simple practice, but frankly it's rarely *needed*